# Dynamically creating DIVs from Database in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, sqldatareader

It is a beginner question. I want to create divs dynamically from database (**MSSQL**). For example, i want to show comments below an entry. The **Comment** table connected with **Entry** table by **EntryID**. My aspx code is like:

```
<div class="commentBody" runat="server">
      <asp:Label ID="commentSender" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
      <asp:Label ID="commentDate" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
      <asp:Label ID="commentText" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
</div>
```

This will be repeat for all comments. And I am working all codebehind (without evals). My c# code:

```
protected void YorumlariGetir()
{   
    string selectComments = "SELECT * FROM Comment WHERE Comment.EntryID = @EntryID";

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constr);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectComments, conn);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EntryID", Session["EntryID"].ToString());

    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        // HERE I WANT TO CALL A LOOP FOR COMMENTS

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write("Hata: " + ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

I can use repeaters or foreach loop. But i don't know how and need an example at this point.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Have you googled "repeater C# asp.net"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EDIT: Answer fully revised.

In your question you ask for a way to do looping and add comments on each loop iteration. You can do this but there are far better ways using built in ASP.NET controls. I will first show you a basic example that simply iterates the SqlDataReader object and manually creates HTML. Then I will show a much better solution. I do not recommend the first option if you are able to implement the second one.

On both solutions, I strongly suggest to specifically name your fields in the select query instead of using an asterisk to select all fields. Using `SELECT *` can cause issues if the table structure changes. Also, you may be selecting data columns you do not need which wastes resources.

First, here is very simple example using the [SqlDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class. This will work, but remember there is a better way.

```
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        // HERE I WANT TO CALL A LOOP FOR COMMENTS
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            // create the div to wrap around the comment
            HtmlGenericControl div = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
            div.Attributes.Add("style", "commentBody");

            // create three labels and add them to the div
            // 1,2,3 are the ordinal positions of the column names, this may need corrected since I have no idea what your table looks like.
            div.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = reader.GetString(1) });
            div.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = reader.GetString(2) });
            div.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = reader.GetString(3) });

            // add the div to the page somehow, these can be added to any HTML control that can act as a container. I would suggest a plain old div.
            MyMainDiv.Controls.Add(div);

        }
    }
```

Now, the above method will work, but it is a clumsy, old-fashioned, way to handle displaying data. Modern .NET applications should use better solutions where available. A better solution would be to use [Data Binding](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307860). There are many articles and tutorials on this across the Internet, so if this is a new idea, you can do some tutorials to learn the finer points of Data Binding.

To use the Repeater class, first add a Repeater control to your ASPX page:

```
<asp:Repeater id="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="commentBody">
            <span class="commentSender"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"aucommentSenderid") %></span>
            <span class="commentDate"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"aucommentDateid") %></span>
            <span class="commentText"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"aucommentTextid") %></span>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Next, add some code-behind to create a datasource and attach this to the Repeater control:

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);      // use your existing SqlCommand here (don't use select *)
DataSet ds = new DataSet();                       // create a DataSet object to hold you table(s)... this can contain more than 1 table
da.Fill(ds, "Comment");                           // fill this dataset with everything from the Comment Table
Repeater1.DataSource = ds.Tables["Comment"];      // attach the data table to the control
Repeater1.DataBind();                             // This causes the HTML to be automatically rendered when the page loads.
```

Comment: I am really sorry but this has nothing to do with question. I am not saying you are wrong, but you are out of context.

Comment: @danish, the question stated **very specifically** "I want to create divs dynamically from database", I thought this was correct.

Comment: OP looks confused here. He doesn't really need multiple divs. He can do this with anything that supports IListSource for data binding. I may be wrong here.

Comment: I agree that this is a basic approach (I will add a note saying its basic). I actually did this intentionally to demonstrate some elementary techniques for iterating SqlDataReader and "doing things" with it.

Comment: OK, I am not a frequent here so I don't know how you guys work. But this approach is not right IMHO. Just because you can do it does not mean you should. I am sorry. OP might end up creating hundreds of divs manually rather than using a straight up control.

Comment: I suggest you offer a solution also, and you can note why it's better than mine. I won't be offended :]

Comment: For my own personal gain... The repeater would create just as many objects as my manual iterations. The only difference is the Repeater creates the HTML automatically using the datasource versus creating it manually with a new statement. Are you indicating there is some performance issue at play here?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43709/discussion-between-danish-and-david-r)

Comment: @DavidR Thank you so much for this brilliant article. That was exactly what I'm looking for. I used the second way and it works smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

As Phill Sandler suggested you can used repeater.Check out the following link for complete code.

[Create Dynamic Control using Repeater and List](http://aspdotnetcodebook.blogspot.in/2008/05/create-dynamic-control-using-repeater.html)